Using Colima how can I expose a containerd socket to the host?
I'm developing an application using containerd as the container runtime. I want to use Colima for development on my Mac. The problem is that Colima doesn't seem to expose the containerd socket on the host the way it does for a docker socket. I'm on Colima version 0.6.8.
Would I be correct in assuming that this feature is just not yet implemented in Colima?
When using the docker runtime I get the docker.sock where I'd expect it:
➜  temp colima start --runtime docker
INFO[0000] starting colima
INFO[0000] runtime: docker
INFO[0000] starting ...                                  context=vm
INFO[0023] provisioning ...                              context=docker
INFO[0024] starting ...                                  context=docker
INFO[0026] done
➜  temp ls ~/.colima/default
colima.yaml daemon      docker.sock

When using the containerd runtime there is no socket on host:
➜  temp colima start --runtime containerd
INFO[0000] starting colima
INFO[0000] runtime: containerd
INFO[0000] starting ...                                  context=vm
INFO[0023] provisioning ...                              context=containerd
INFO[0024] starting ...                                  context=containerd
INFO[0025] done
➜  temp ls ~/.colima/default
colima.yaml daemon

I can see the socket does exist within the VM however:
➜  temp colima ssh sudo ls -l /run/containerd/containerd.sock
/run/containerd/containerd.sock


Looked at the source code and it seems that forwarding the socket is indeed only supported for Docker at the moment.
